# AngularJS - controller doesn't get data from service when using $http

Tags: angularjs, http, service, controller, is-empty

I have simple web app where I like to load some data from json. At the moment the data is hardcoded within my service and everything is working.

When I change my service to load the same data from an external json file the controller renders the view before it gets some data.

**That's what it looks like now:**

```
function() {
var tripsService = function() {

var trips = [{ .... SOME DATA }];

this.getTrips = function() {
            return trips;
        };

};



angular.module('customersApp').service('tripsService', tripsService);
}());
```

**Using $http.get :**

```
function() {
var tripsService = function() {

 var trips = [];

this.getTrips = function() {

$http.get('trips.json').success(function (data) {
            var trips = data;
            return trips;
           });
     };

};



angular.module('customersApp').service('tripsService', tripsService);
}());
```

Here is my Plunker:

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/btwq6grwIYDaKi06OhEo?p=preview)

What can I do to change this ? I have read something about adding resolve property to my routeProvider but I wasn't able to solve the problem !

Update: Maybe my description wasn't precise enough and I have to learn some more about handling data ! The data from json should just load once, so that any view change wouldn't reload the original json file.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to learn about promises:
http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/

In the service you should return directly the promise of the call to the `$http`-Service:

```
    this.getTrips = function() {
         return $http.get('trips.json').then(function (response) {
            trips = response.data;
            return trips;
          });
    };
```

In the controller you have then to call the `then`-method to access the data from the service:

```
    function init() {
        tripsService.getTrips().then(function(trips) {
          $scope.trips = trips;
        })
    }
```

Here is a updated Plunker with a working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/QEvKMtKvhf49uIpNu5h8?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But now my data is loaded everytime I go back to Trips, which makes any changes useless I made in the edit section  ! As I imported the data hardcoded I could change my data !

Comment: Then you simply have to check if you loaded the data already before you reload them

Comment: I tried something like this:                                                                                   var loaded = false;

        this.getTrips = function() {
            
            if(loaded == false){
             return $http.get('trips.json').then(function (response) {
                trips = response.data;
                var loaded = true;
                return trips;
              });
            } else {
              return trips;
              alert('test');
            }
        };  -----> doesn't work ! Maybe you have any tip ?

Comment: I updated the Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/QEvKMtKvhf49uIpNu5h8?p=preview Here I cache the data in the service. Take a look at: https://github.com/iterativ/angularjsbestpracticesapp for a bigger example

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the view when you retrieved the content you indeed need a route resolve.

You can do that by.

```
$routeProvider
.when("/someRoute", {
    templateUrl: "sometemplat.html",
    controller: "someController",
    resolve: {
        trips: function(tripsService){
            return tripsService.getTrips();
       }
   }
})
```

This will resolve a variable called trips into the controller.

you need to add the trips to your controller dependencies.

And if everything works trips should be filled with the data from the api.