# Unexpected behaviors of promises

Tags: angularjs

I've been facing a trouble while working with Factory/Service. I've created an AjaxRequests factory for all of my AJAX calls. My factory code is

```
.factory('AjaxRequests', ['$http', function ($http) {
                return {
                    getCampaignsData: function () {
                        var campaigns
                        return $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
                            campaigns = response.data;
                            return campaigns;
                        });

                    }
                }
            }])
```

I've created another service in which I am injecting this factory. My service code

```
.service('CampaignsService', ['$rootScope', 'AjaxRequests', function ($rootScope, AjaxRequests) {
     this.init = function () {
     this.camps;
     AjaxRequests.getCampaignsData().then(function (response) {
       this.camps = response.campaigns;
       console.log(this.camps); // It is showing data
     })
     console.log(this.camps); // But it is not working :(
    };
   this.init();

}])
```

And in my controller

```
.controller('AdvanceSettingsController', ['$scope', 'CampaignsService', function ($scope, CampaignsService) {
                $scope.CampaignsService = CampaignsService;
            }
        ])
```

I've read this [article](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/) to learn promises but it is not working here. I can directly achieve it in controller and it's been working fine. But it consider as a bad coding standard to make controller thick. But when I use service and factory I stuck. **My question is why I am not getting ajax data to use in my whole service ?** I need to use `CampaignsService.camps` in my view template as well as in my whole rest script but every time I get `undefined`. What is happening here? I've asked the same question before but couldn't get any success. **Some one please help me to understand about promises and why I am getting this type of error if I'm working same** ? This type of question has already been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30369483/angularjs-controller-doesnt-get-data-from-service-when-using-http) but it was working in controller. May be I am stuck because I'm using it in a service.

A big thanks in advance.

Comment: In my experience you don't need `CampaignsService`, You should directly use `AjaxRequests.getCampaignsData().then(function (response) {
       $scope.camps = response.campaigns;
     })` in your controller

Comment: Okay, so what I could do instead. Actually I've already wrap up my complete code in this service but before I was working on static data. I stuck when I use service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug or some tricky functionality. Just like in any other AJAX implementation, you can only access the response data in AngularJS's `$http` `success` method. That's because of the *asynchronous* nature  of Asynchronous JavaScript And XML.

And what you have is working.

```
.controller('AdvanceSettingsController', ['$scope', 'AjaxRequests', function ($scope, AjaxRequests) {
        $scope.camps = [];
        AjaxRequests.getCampaignsData().then(function(data) {
             $scope.camps = data;
        });
    }
])
```

And then bind `camps`:

```
<div ng-repeat="camp in camps>{{camp.name}}</div>
```

What's *bad* in your implementation is that instead of grouping related stuff in services you are writing a big `AjaxRequests` service for everything. You should have a `CampaignsService` that has a `getData` method and inject that in your controller.

Why is this working? Because `$http` does a `$scope.$apply` for you, which triggers a digest cycle *after* the data is loaded (`then`) and updates the HTML. So before the `then` callback that `ng-repeat` is run with `[]` and *after* it it's again run but with data from the response because you are  setting `$scope.camps = data;`.

The reason `<div ng-repeat="camp in CampaignsService.camps>{{camp.name}}</div>` does not work is because of [function variable scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript).

The `this` reference inside of your `then` callback is not the same as the `this` reference outside of it.

This will work and uses the common `var self = this` trick:

```
var self = this;
this.camps = [];
this.init = function () {
    AjaxRequests.getCampaignsData().then(function (response) {
        // here "this" is not the one from outside.
        // "self" on the other hand is!
        self.camps = response.campaigns;
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to share this useful information. I got your point and I'll change my code structure as per you've mentioned but here is my last question. Why $scope.CampaignsService = CampaignsService; not works in controller ?

Comment: It is working with another functions except $http service. If my another function changes any object and I am using this object in view, then by using above line the digest cycle automatically start.